# WebPhone and SoftPhone with Asterisk13

Tags: asterisk, sip, rtp

I have a problem with Asterisk. I wrote a WebPhone, so I should add to my peers some config details:

```
encryption = yes
avpf = yes
icesupport = yes
dtlsenable =yes
dtlsverify = no
dtlssetup = actpass
dtlscertfile = valid path to certyficate
dtlsprivatekey = valid path to certyficate
force_avp = yes
```

And all is working with webphone. But when I want to call from my peer (with config above) from softphone (like zoiper or linphone) I received an error "488 Not acceptable here bearer capability not presently available" and in Asterisk console:

```
[Oct 27 12:00:23] NOTICE[2214][C-00000001]: chan_sip.c:10148 process_sdp: Received AVP profile in audio answer but AVPF is enabled, disabling: audio 8000 RTP/AVP 3 110 8 0 98 101
[Oct 27 12:00:23] WARNING[2214][C-00000001]: chan_sip.c:10543 process_sdp: We are requesting SRTP for audio, but they responded without it!
```

And my question is simple.. Can I configure Asterisk peer that it can work with softphone and webphone?  :)

Thanks in advance!
Matt.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the same peer both for softphone and webphone.
But in this case you'll have to configure the softphone a little bit different.
In your example you have to enable SRTP in your zoiper (and probably TLS).